# Rails Associations error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing code for an e-commerce site, like Aliexpress or Amazon where there are many stores (Sellers) who can own their own shit like products etc, in short I have a User, who owns a store, and the store owns a post. I decided to hook the post to the store because it would help keep posts linked together with post related store and posts would include updates to customers etc

this is the code section generating the error:

```
def create
@post = current_user.stores.posts.build(post_params)
```

and the error is:

```
undefined method `posts' for <Store::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x000000051308f8>
```

I have corrected everything including the has_many :post and belongs_to :store

I would appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
@post = current_user.stores.posts.build(post_params)
```

Specifically, `stores.posts`, you're asking for the `posts` without having selected a single `Store`, you're asking the collection of `stores` for the `posts`, which is incorrect.  You need to select a single store, or change how you model things depending on what you really want.

Comment: Hi! I had changed that to stores.first and it returned an "unknown method posts" error

Comment: Post your User, Store and Post objects so we can see if things are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, there is no method `posts` for a collections of `stores`. `posts` is only available for one instance of `Store`.

You would need to find the store for which you want to build the `post`. Something like that should work (depending on your routes implementation):

```
def create
  @store = current_user.stores.find(params[:store_id])
  @post = @store.posts.build(post_params)
end
```